# Can I make a character solid but not lose non-physics behaviour?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, rigid-body-dynamics

My character can walk around in the world, but walks through other objects, for example a cylinder (stand-in for a cannon). To fix this I added a capsule collider to each of the character and cylinder, but that wasn't enough. Apparently I have to add a Rigidbody as well. [[1]](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider.html) [[2]](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34978)

When I add a Rigidbody to either one, they collide as expected. However, when I add a Rigidbody to my character, it falls over when I move forward. When I add a Rigidbody to my cylinder, other functionality fails (it is supposed to shoot cannonballs, and they act strangely). If I enable Kinematics on either, they stop colliding.

Is there any other way to make the character and cylinder solid with respect to each other, without breaking existing non-physics functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a character controller and use controller.move() with this you can make your character don't walk through the walls, if this wall have a collider.

Answer (score 1):

You can [freeze](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-freezeRotation.html) rotations of a `Rigidbody`.

Comment: (Please refrain from link only.)